# Event in a button of each Item of a Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` loaded from **Firebase** data, I need to add a functionality to a button that is in each item, which is to add a product to the shopping cart.

The problem I have happens when there is more than one item in the recycler, since clicking the button adds an item correctly, but the others can no longer be added.

What I want is to do the `onclik` for each item and apparently it only takes me once.

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, final Menu model, int position) {

        final String item_id  = getRef(position).getKey();

        final String rest_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("rest_id");

        viewHolder.setName(model.getNombre());
        viewHolder.setDescrpcion(model.getDescripcion());
        viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getThumb_image());
        viewHolder.agregaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mEstado_pedidos.equals("sin_pedidos")){

                    Map pedidoMap = new HashMap();
                    pedidoMap.put("Solicitud_Pedido/"+mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + rest_id + "/" + item_id + "/tipo_pedido", "solicitado");
                    pedidoMap.put("Solicitud_Pedido/"+rest_id + "/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + item_id +"/tipo_pedido", "recibido");

                    mRootRef.updateChildren(pedidoMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if (databaseError != null){

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                            fab.setEnabled(true);
                            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            mEstado_pedidos = "con_pedido";
                            Button agregaBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);
                            agregaBtn.setText("Eliminar del carrito");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        final String list_user_id  = getRef(position).getKey();

        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is the class `Viewholder`

```
public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    Button agregaBtn;


    public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        agregaBtn = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);
    }


    public void setName(String nombre){

        TextView mName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_item);
        mName.setText(nombre);
    }

    public void setDescrpcion(String descrpcion){

        TextView mDescripcion = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_item);
        mDescripcion.setText(descrpcion);
    }

    public void setImage(final Context context, String thumb_image){

        ImageView mImagen = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_item);
        Picasso.with(context).load(thumb_image).into(mImagen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.. Can you post the code starting from `adapter` assignment above `propulateviewholder` and update question with an example/screenshots if possible..

Comment: you need to check if item is added to the cart, I dont see how do you check if is added or not. how do you check if item is added to the cart

Comment: Hi +Bruno Ferreira hablas español o portugués?  Para poder explicar mejor porque no se hablar bien inglés

Comment: I speak portuguese.

Comment: Eu não sei como implementar se cada item adicionado ao carrinho :(

Comment: Did you solve your problem. I also wanted like this. Set Onclickistener for automatically added items using firebase recycle adapter.    @juan Solano

Answer (score -1):

Just taking a wild wild guess, have you checked this lines ?

```
   if (mEstado_pedidos.equals("sin_pedidos"){
    //some logic
     mEstado_pedidos = "con_pedido";

   }
```

I'm not sure about this mEstado_pedidos variable but it looks like it works the first time since it's probably initialized as "sin_pedidos" but it then turns in something different inside the "if" block. Basically the OnClickListener works just fine but the "if" block doesn't work since mEstado_pedidos never turns back to "sin_pedidos" after the first time.

EDIT, after translating some lines with google i understood this is some kind of shopping card and you need to check if the object from the RecyclerView is already on the cart or not. If that's the case :

-Let's say you are populating your recycler view from an "item node" in the database with this ref :

```
DatabaseReference myList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("List");
```

Each item in the list has it's own id

-Let's say your user cart is stored at

```
DatabaseReference myCartRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Carts").child(my_user_id);
```

inside this node you'll add all the item id's which you want to add

You are already declaring

```
 final String item_id  = getRef(position).getKey();
```

So inside the OnclickListener you can call :

```
myCartRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               //if your cart reference doesn't have the current item
               if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(item_id){
                   myCartRed.child(item_id).setValue(true); 
               }
          }
```

Comment: Yes, so, but how can I make each item in the recyclerview listen for the variable (con_pedido) or (sin_pedido)?

Comment: it would be usefull to see where you declared "mEstado_pedidos" in the first place and why/when you need to check if it has some value...just give us more information about this variable

Comment: Okay, I'll try what you wrote and in a few hours I comment. Thank you